# How to move elements via XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML.

```
 <body>
  <p type="Heading 1">My Heading</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text... <p type="Key Words">This is a keyword A</p></p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text... <p type="Key Words">This is a keyword B</p></p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p type="Heading 1">My Next Heading</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... <p type="Key Words">This is a keyword C</p>This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p type="Heading 2">My Next Heading</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... <p type="Key Words">This is a keyword D</p> This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
</body>
```

I would like to move all of the "Key Words" to just before the next heading as shown below:

```
<body>
  <p type="Heading 1">My Heading</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p type="Key Words">This is a keyword A</p>
  <p type="Key Words">This is a keyword B</p>
  <p  type="Heading 1">My Next Heading</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p type="Key Words">This is a keyword C</p>
  <p  type="Heading 2">My Next Heading</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text...  This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p>This is paragraph Text... This is paragraph text...</p>
  <p type="Key Words">This is a keyword D</p>
</body>
```

I have code that works, but it has serious performance problems because I am running this transform on documents that have 10's of thousands of words. Below is my current code.

```
<!-- Place all keywords in section right before the next heading title. -->
<xsl:template match="p[contains(@type,'Heading')]">

  <xsl:variable name="headingCount" >
    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::p[contains(@type,'Heading')])"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="precedingKeyWordCount">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::p[contains(@type,'Key Words') and count(preceding::p[contains(@type,'Heading')]) = $headingCount])"/>
  </xsl:variable>


  <xsl:if test="$precedingKeyWordCount > 0" >
    <p type="Key Words">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding::p[contains(@type,'Key Words') and count(preceding::p[contains(@type,'Heading')]) = $headingCount]" />
    </p>
  </xsl:if>


  <!-- place original heading -->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>


</xsl:template>
```

Does anyone know a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly simpler example (that assumes `Key Words` paragraphs can be copied to the output in full):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="byHeading" match="p[@type='Key Words']" 
             use="generate-id(following::p[starts-with(@type, 'Heading')][1])"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('byHeading', '')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p[starts-with(@type, 'Heading')]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('byHeading', generate-id())"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p[@type='Key Words']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The primary issue with your original stylesheet is that it needs to look at every preceding element in the document multiple times for each heading. The `preceding` and `following` axes often cause performance issues on large documents.

We can avoid this performance problem by grouping up-front with a `key`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1" 
    match="p/p[@type = 'Key Words']"
    use="generate-id(parent::p/following-sibling::p[starts-with(@type, 'Heading')][1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', '')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body/p[starts-with(@type, 'Heading')]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', generate-id())"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body/p[not(@type) or not(starts-with(@type, 'Heading'))]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::p[@type = 'Key Words'])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That should perform better.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution that is not dependent on the structure body/p/p.

Comment: Okay, I think I was able to tweek it. Thanks for the help!